# Probability of voting

Tags: probability, probability-theory, queueing-theory

One hundred students are divided into two equal groups. Both groups vote (yes or no). Find the probability that the groups 1 and 2 both reach a majority.

Students vote independently and the probability for each student to vote yes ½. A majority can be achieved with either yes or no votes.

Comment: Sounds like a reasonable start. Are you stuck on the calculating "probability of a tie" part?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The probability of a tie is
$$P_{tie}=\frac{\binom{50}{25}}{2^{50}}$$
thus the probability that neither group reaches a tie is
$$P = (1-P_{tie})^2$$
(where all events are assumed to be independent). This gives
$$P = \left(1 - \frac{\binom{50}{25}}{2^{50}}\right)^2 \approx \left(1 - \frac{1}{5\sqrt{\pi}}\right)^2\approx 0.79$$
where in the second step we approximated using Stirling's formula.